# Why to "Make autowired dependencies explicit"?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

When I'm writing some spring xml configs, I personnally prefer to set `default-autowire="byName"`.

But in Idea 14, the IDE warns me to "Make autowired dependencies explicit".

So here comes the question, whats the advantage of making spring bean wire explicit?

Comment: Isn't it autowire="default" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage is that you can review the object graph in a centralized way, as opposed to having to chase down dependencies distributed across a bunch of class files, component scans and so forth.

The disadvantage is that your app config is larger. More code/config to manage.

Either style works. I tend to start with autowiring and then migrate toward explicit dependencies as the app gets larger.